# How do I carry data from one page to the next in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

Say I have a page with a link to another page. When I click on the link, I need data (several, not just one or two) from the current page to be available when I enter the link. I'm using Laravel. How can this be achieved or what words of advice is there for my situation.

Because it's Laravel and MVC, I'm not sure whether I'm supposed to approach it in a certain light.

Comment: What kind of data? It it user-input? Is it in the DB? What have you tried?

Comment: Data from the DB I guess. I call an API to fetch data transferred in JSON and I display some of that data. I want to display some data on the second page as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean. I would inject the data from the controller.

If you are passing data from one page to another either post the data from page one and return that data to page two through the controller. Or you could use props in the URL to pass data as long as it's not sensitive data.

I would recommend reading the docs for Laravel. If it is data from the db you want.

Answer (score 0):

Put the data you wish to persist across multiple pages in the session.

When you serve page #1, have your controller put data in the user's session, and then retrieve that data from page #2.

You can read more about session data here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest working your way through this, before you continue with Laravel development:

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals